# Expo web uses the wrong base uri to load assets if you use deep linking

Tags: django, react-native-web, expo-web

I built a web version of my app using `expo web` and `react-navigation`, and I am serving it using `Django`.
I managed to make everything work when I go on `mywebsite.com` and navigate around.

However, if I load my website directly on `mywebsite.com/OTHER/PAGE`, this piece of code fails:

```
await Asset.loadAsync([require("../../assets/images/Logo.png")]),
```

after some investigation, I found out that instead of loading this asset:

```
http://mywebsite.com/web-build/static/media/Logo.ceb44efe.png
```

it tries to load that one (that doesn't exist):

```
http://mywebsite.com/OTHER/PAGE/web-build/static/media/Logo.ceb44efe.png
```

How can I tell it to only use `http://mywebsite.com/` as a base URI when loading assets?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My homepage in `package.json` was set to `"homepage": "web-build"`, and it should have been `"homepage": "/web-build"`